# Read UDP packet stream into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, udp, protocols, middleware

I have a device that broadcasts a UDP ASCII stream on my network and I want to receive and parse that stream into my db.

Do I need to buy or build UDP receiver middleware to do the protocol conversion or can this be done inside of SQL Server 2017 without third-party tools?

Comment: Middleware, this is not a job for a database server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have someone with some coding knowledge, you could implement your UDP receiver in powershell  [see this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148666/send-and-receive-data-via-udp-in-powershell)
 and then send whatever data you received to your database. [see here for example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289310.aspx)

In any case I would rather put that outside of the DB itself.

But if you feel like it must be within the DB, maybe it's possible to do it with stored procedure.